# bot not responding after converting it as a skill

Tags: c#, botframework, direct-line-botframework

I have tried to convert my existing v4 bot to a skill. Now it is not showing any error while building. But in the emulator I'm not getting any response.

screenshot from emulator

[image]

Can any one help me to know where to start with debugging ?

I have followed the steps from [https://microsoft.github.io/botframework-solutions/howto/skills/skillenablingav4bot/](https://microsoft.github.io/botframeworksolutions/howto/skills/skillenablingav4bot/)

I didn't had Adapters or BotSettings class so I created both here is the code that I have added

CustomSkillAdapter.cs

```html
 public class CustomSkillAdapter : SkillWebSocketBotAdapter
    {
        public CustomSkillAdapter(
            BotSettings settings,
            BotStateSet botStateSet,
            ConversationState conversationState,
            ResponseManager responseManager,
            IBotTelemetryClient telemetryClient,
            UserState userState)
            : base()
        {

            Use(new SkillMiddleware(userState, conversationState, conversationState.CreateProperty<DialogState>(nameof(DialogState))));
        }
    }
```

DefaultAdapter.cs

```html
 public class DefaultAdapter : BotFrameworkHttpAdapter
    {
        public DefaultAdapter(
           BotSettings settings,
           ICredentialProvider credentialProvider,
           IBotTelemetryClient telemetryClient,
           ResponseManager responseManager)
           : base(credentialProvider)
        {
            

            Use(new TranscriptLoggerMiddleware(new AzureBlobTranscriptStore(settings.BlobStorage.ConnectionString, settings.BlobStorage.Container)));
            Use(new TelemetryLoggerMiddleware(telemetryClient, logPersonalInformation: true));
            Use(new ShowTypingMiddleware());
            Use(new SetLocaleMiddleware(settings.DefaultLocale ?? "en-us"));
            Use(new EventDebuggerMiddleware());
        }
    }
```

BotSettings it is actually blank

```html
public class BotSettings : BotSettingsBase
    {
    }
```

Comment: Can you explaib, how you converted it. Also to reproduce your problem, it is helpful to have at leat some code how your bot works.

Comment: @nbk these are the extra codes that I have added.